# Can i check the changed contents through hyperledger fabric transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently participating in the hyperledger fabric project.

The concept of hyperledger fabric is still insufficient. I understand that the transaction is stored in the block. The transaction knows that the chaincode is executed.

For example, suppose you executed send chaincode. Suppose A sends 500 to B with A = 1000 and B = 1000. It will be A = 500 and B = 1500. Suppose this is TxId = AAA.

I want to see AAA's history of "A sent 500 to B" in this situation. Mychannel.block and mychannel in the channel-artifact directory created by running the current network.I tried to decode tx to json file.

However, it was found that there was no content related to this. Is there any way I can see the contents of TxId=AAA?

Decode .tx and .block file. but I didn't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the history of transactions, you can use the ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(id) function, where the id parameter is a record key. This is the Node.js SDK method, I expect that it is similarly named for Java and Go. I think that the information that you require should be held in the contract, as the history only returns the different contract versions over time. If you want to see that A transacted with B, you would need the contract code to show that funds came from A and landed with B during the transfer. Depending on implementation, this might require a cross-contract call to a different contract (one containing clients A and B) so that 500 could be taken from Account A's fund and added to Account B's fund. In this scenario (if we are talking about a sale), the AssetTransfer contract could show the change of ownership, whereas the client contract will show 2 updates, one where A's fund decreases by 500 and another where B's fund increases by 500.

In the scenario above, there are now three updates that have history i.e. an asset sale, which you don't mention, but I am using as an example which will have a change of ownership history. A client A, whose fund record will have decreased, and a client B, who will have a corresponding increase in funds. Therefore, it's not a block history that you require, but a history of the Client records for A and B. Even if you only had a single contract e.g. (Client), and you exchanged funds, you will still have two updates, one for A and the other for B. It's the records within the contract code that change. The block is the manifestation of the entire transaction i.e. all rules have been satisfied by the different peers and whatever concensus policy is in place.